# XSLT: output unmatched elements from two pieces of xml

Tags: xslt

The two sample xmls are given below:

xml1:

```
<Root>
  <Child1/>
  <Child2/>
  <Child3/>
</Root>
```

xml2:

```
<Root>
  <Child0>xml2value</Child0>
  <Child2/>
  <Child3>xml2value</Child3>
  <Child4>xml2value</Child4>
</Root>
```

I have got these two xmls in two variables. Now I want to filter from xml2 those elements which do not exist in xml1, i.e., the resulting variable should look like below:

```
<Child0>xml2value</Child0>
<Child4>xml2value</Child4>
```

How can it be done with xslt?

Comment: This link will hep you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245346/filtering-xml-tags-using-xslt

Answer (score 2):

XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:key name="el-by-name" match="Root/*" use="node-name(.)"/>

<xsl:variable name="xml1" select="document('file1.xml')"/>
<xsl:variable name="xml2" select="document('file2.xml')"/>

<xsl:copy-of select="$xml2/Root/*[not(key('el-by-name', node-name(.), $xml1))]"/>
```

With XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:key name="el-by-name" match="Root/*" use="name()"/>

<xsl:variable name="xml1" select="document('file1.xml')"/>
<xsl:variable name="xml2" select="document('file2.xml')"/>

<xsl:for-each select="$xml2/Root/*">
  <xsl:variable name="child" select="."/>
  <xsl:for-each select="$xml1">
    <xsl:if test="not(key('el-by-name', name($child)))">
      <xsl:copy-of select="$child"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem with the below code:

```
               <xsl:variable name="output">
                <xsl:for-each select="$xml2/Root/*">
                  <xsl:variable name="cur" select="local-name(.)"/>
                  <xsl:if test="not($xml1/Root/*[local-name(.)=$cur])">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                  </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
               </xsl:variable>
```